# Active Directory Domain Services on remote VPS

Tags: active-directory, domain, vps, domain-controller

I really need help with configuring Active Directory Domain Services on a remote VPS.

**Situation**

we have a remote Windows Server 2008R2 VPS and i just installed the Active Directory Domain Services Role. A DNS Server was also configured by default at the end of the Active Directory installation.

**Problem**

I can't get my Windows 7 machine to register itself to the domain i have just created

**Question**

What are the steps i have to take to test my Active Directory configuration, and how do i connect clients to this Domain?

I can provide screenshots and more information if neccesary.

Comment: How is the Win7-client configured? How are the server and client connected?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Windows 7 machine configured to use your ADDS server as its DNS server?

If so, can you ping the domain name? What I mean by this is, if the server is called MyDC.MyDomain.Com

Then can you ping / resolve

> MyDomain.com

(This should return the IP address of your DC)